How to use a string in javascript function
I have a button
onclick="click(' . $item . ');"

then the javascript function is supposed to pass $item to another page. It works fine if $item is a number, but not if it's a string, and sometimes it's a mix of characters and numbers which I can't control.
function click(c)
{
var u = "items.php?serial=" + c;
document.location.href = u;
}

Is there a way to do this in JS?

could you try using var u = "items.php?serial="+encodeURIComponent(u)
this will encode the data in u suitable for url

@SanuKhan this works if I use +encodeURIComponent(c), thanks. Make an answer and I'll accept it

Why a button with javascript attached? Just make a hyperlink and it will navigate to the URL you specify without needing any script. (And if you want to give the link the appearance of a button you can do that easily with CSS). Always keep it simple!

@ADyson because the javascript does other important things before it gets to this bit.

@Kilisi try using backticks (``)

@NalanPandiKumar I'm not the person asking the question

@ADyson sorry for the misunderstanding.

It's important to understand that escaping is not something you can do "once and for all", but something you do each time you pass something from one context to another. In this case, you're passing from PHP to JS, and then from JS to a URL, so I've linked two existing answers that cover those two steps. You need to apply both types of escaping, at the right points in your code.

@IMSoP how so? I have 2 solutions both of which work, why would I need the ones in your links of 14 answers and 16 answers which at first glance seem very different

@Kilisi because stackoverflow doesn't need multiple duplicate questions on the same topic. We aim to merge such things into a small number of posts so it's easier for people to research- although I don't know why you didn't find such info already as well. Remember this is an encyclopaedia, not a helpdesk

@ADyson sure, I'm not querying the closure. I'm querying your comment that I need to escape twice, when once seems to work fine. I'm not against doing so, just if it works why fix it?

Using the wrong escape function for a particular context may well work for some values, but not all; at best, that might mean it's fine for years and then breaks later when you change something; at worst, it might allow a malicious user to trick your code into exposing your server or your other users to a serious security breach. It may be that the code you've written is accidentally safe in this case, but it's really important to understand the principles of why particular escape functions are needed, because if you just guess each time you will get it seriously wrong one day.

Rather than thinking of it as "escaping twice", you could think of it as "escaping without looking at the rest of the code": when you write the JS code to build a URL with a dynamic part, you can ignore where that part is coming from, and know that encodeUriComponent will do the right thing; and when you write some PHP code that's generating dynamic JavaScript, you can ignore what the JS is going to do next, and just make sure the JS is valid. Working out the full path of the code, and whether you can escape only once, actually requires more effort, once you get into those good habits.

@Kilisi I didn't make that comment, IMSoP did, but it's certainly correct.

@IMSoP that makes perfect sense, thanks.

The problem is that $item may contain some content that botches up your functionality. You have
onclick="click(' . $item . ');"

but what if $item is O'Brian? In that case this translated to
onclick="click('O'Brian');"

so what actually happens, you are to pass a string to click which is O but it will not work. See:


function click(c)
{
    var u = "items.php?serial=" + c;
    document.location.href = u;
}
<input type="button" onclick="click('O'Brian')" value="something">



You will get a complain about the paranthesis not being closed, because after closing the string O it expects the bracket of the function to be closed, but it gets Brian instead.
Since the suggested encodeURIComponent is a Javascript function (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) that you are to run for c according to the suggestion, it will not resolve your issue by itself. You will need to prevent errors from occurring by adding slashes, like
onclick="click(' . addslashes($item) . ');"

and then call encodeURIComponent inside your JS function, like
function click(c)
{
    var u = "items.php?serial=" + encodeURIComponent(c);
    document.location.href = u;
}


Very comprehensive, thanks

Your explanation is brilliant, up to the part where you start talking about URL-encoding, which is a completely different context. Will the function you give even help for the O'Brien example? As the rest of your answer hints, the key is nothing to do with URLs, but ensuring you create valid JavaScript source code; one trick for that is to use json_encode, because valid JSON is also valid JS source code.

The string is later used in a URL, but that's in the JS code, so can use the JS encodeUriComponent function. Always resist the temptation to "pre-escape" content for multiple contexts at once, you'll just get yourself into a mess.

@IMSoP thanks for the comments, you are right. I have edited my answer accordingly, even though I do not encode a string as JSON to avoid further issues with the quotes. I rather add slashes :)

Try this:
onclick="click(\'' . $item . '\');"

The escaped quotes are what you need.

it doesn't give me a valid url it gives "items.php?serial="%20+%20c

@Kilisi can you add the php code that creates the button in your post please?

It's ok, it's now been fixed in the js function from a comment above. Gave you a vote for your effort as I see you're on another track that would also work. So I used your answer and the idea from the comment and it's now working.
